# using the method onclick () to trigger a function that opens a window it grabs from the clicked button

Tags: javascript, function, methods, onsubmit

```
    <script language="JavaScript">

         function goThere()
        {
                var the_url = window.document.form.button.value;
                var good_url = fixURL(the_url);
                var new_window = window.open(good_url,"new_window","menubar,resizeable");
        }

        function fixURL(the_url)
        {
                var the_first_seven = the_url.substring(0,7);
                the_first_seven = the_first_seven.toLowerCase();
                if (the_first_seven != 'http://') 
                {
                        the_url = "http://" + the_url;
                }
                return the_url;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="the_form" onclick="goThere()"; return false;">


    <input type="button" name="the_url" class="broadGroups" onClick="goThere()" value="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Sports"></input>

    <input type="button" name="the_url" class="broadGroups" onclick="goThere()" value="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Film"></input>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So this code may be totally messed up, but here is what I am trying to do.

There are two buttons inside the  tag. I want each to use the method onsubmit to trigger the function goThere(). How do I set it up so that the_url is set to a value that I pull from the button tag. I also want to be able to put non-url text on the button itself while allowing it to call goThere () through the method call onsubmit.

In the end it should just take the url, make sure it starts with http:// (in this case it doesnt matter because the user isn't inputting the url, but I'd like to keep it in for other purposes later on) and open it in a new window with a menubar and the resizable property.

Sorry for the long post. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in `this` in your `goThere` call. This will bring in the clicked element to your goThere function. Then you access the attributes for the clicked button.

http://jsfiddle.net/wJMgb/

```
onClick="goThere(this)"
```

```
function goThere(elem) {
    var the_url = elem.value;
    var good_url = fixURL(the_url);
    var new_window = window.open(good_url, "new_window", "menubar,resizeable");
}

function fixURL(the_url) {
    var the_first_seven = the_url.substring(0, 7);
    the_first_seven = the_first_seven.toLowerCase();
    if (the_first_seven != 'http://') {
        the_url = "http://" + the_url;
    }
    return the_url;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Question if you don't mind. What is exactly is elem and why did you set it to the argument? How does that help the function?

Comment: Never wouldn't be in this example. might be though if you allow user to input a url and want to call the same function to open a new window using the url they gave

Comment: @NicMeiring - elem is a variable. When you call `goThere(this)`, `this` is passed into the function. `this` is a placeholder for the clicked element. `this` gets renamed to `elem` in the function parameters list to `elem`. Although you could name it anything you want.